# Jinja2 iterating over list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
services:
  some_service:
    service_name: service1
    users:
      - user1
      - user2
  another_service:
    service_name: service2
    users:
      - user3
      - user4
  and_another_one:
    service_name: service3
    users:
      - user5
      - user6
```

Python syntax:

```
services = [{'service_name': 'service1', 'users': ["user1", "user2"]}, {'service_name': 'service2', 'users': ["user3", "user4"]}, {'service_name': 'service3', 'users': ["user5", "user6"]}]
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
user1: service1, service2, service3
user2: service1, service2, service3
user3: service1, service2, service3
user4: service1, service2, service3
user5: service1, service2, service3
user6: service1, service2, service3
```

I'm having a really hard time trying to make this work, so any help would be appreciated. I've already tried a few solutions found here, though no success. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can we see an example of the actual list of dictionaries in proper python syntax ?

Comment: @JacobIRR, edited the question

Comment: what you want to achieve doesn't make any sense to me. All the users with all the 3 services? Please confirm it once.

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ dict(my_users|product([my_srvcs])) }}"
      vars:
        my_users: "{{ services|json_query('*.users')|flatten|unique|sort }}"
        my_srvcs: "{{ services|json_query('*.service_name')|unique|sort }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_dict
```

give

```yaml
  my_dict:
    user1:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
    user2:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
    user3:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
    user4:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
    user5:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
    user6:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3
```